# Errors at runtime vs errors at compile time

Tags: c, compiler-errors, runtime-error

We recently took an exam were we got this question:

Consider this fragment of code:

```
FILE * pFile;
pFile = open ("myfile.txt","w+");
fprintf (pFile, "%f %s", 3.1416, "PI");
```

Which of the following statements are true?

A)The program generates error at compile time

B)The program generates error at runtime

C) . . .

D) . . .

We couldn't use the compiler, and the information wrote is the only thing we had.
The correct answer ended up being B, error at runtime, can someone explain me thoroughly why that is?

I know the compiler generates a warning, but the point here is to understand why the compiler let us compile this code in the first place instead of giving us an error.

My guess is that open, even though doesn't give a pointer back(which is an address), gives the fp which is still an int, so in the eyes of the compiler isn't wrong syntax, but at runtime it probably tries to access a private memory address which leads to an error.

p.s.
I know that the correct function should have been fopen, but that still doesn't explain why

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code has two specific issues:

- The second parameter to `open` expects an `int` but a `char *` is passed instead
- `open` returns an `int` but that value is assigned to a `FILE *`.

The compiler flags these as warnings instead of errors because the language allows a pointer to be converted to an integer, and for an integer to be converted to a pointer.  However, doing so is generally implementation defined and usually (as in this case) but not always indicates a problem.

Section 6.3.2.3 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) describes these conversions:

> *5* An  integer  may  be  converted  to  any  pointer  type.   Except  as  previously  specified,  the result  is  implementation-defined,
> might  not  be  correctly  aligned,  might  not  point  to  an entity
> of the referenced type, and might be a trap representation.
>
> *6* Any pointer type may be converted to an integer type.  Except as previously specified, the result  is  implementation-defined.  If  the
> result  cannot  be  represented  in  the  integer  type,the  behavior
> is  undefined.  The  result  need  not  be  in  the  range  of  values
> of  any integer type.